# Is the function $f(x,y) = xy$ (quasi) concave or (quasi) convex?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, hessian-matrix

> Is the function $f(x,y) = xy$ (quasi) concave or (quasi) convex?

I start by finding the Hessian matrix, which is $H = \begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 \\ 
1 &0 
\end{bmatrix}$.

Then I ask myself if the matrix is negative semi-definite or positive semi-definite.

We have $x'Hx = \begin{bmatrix}
 x_{1}&x_{2} 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 \\ 
1 &0 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1}
&x_{2}
\end{bmatrix} = 2 x_{1} x_{2} $

Since in general $2 x_{1} x_{2}$ can have any sign, we cannot say whether the function is (quasi)convex or (quasi)concave.

Is this correct?

Comment: I copied the problem statement from the title (with minor correction) into the body of your Question.  This seemingly trivial change will help Readers to connect your thoughts.  It would improve your Question to specify the domain for $f(x,y)$ on which you wanted to consider convexity.

Comment: I would think this is easier to prove directly from the definitions: Is $f^{-1}((\infty, 0])$ a convex subset of the plane?

Comment: @hardmath Okay. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Q-concave if $xy>0$, q-convex if $xy<0$.

Comment: Would a Principal Minor Method be a good idea here? I've found that $|H_{1}| = 0$ and $|H_{2}| = |H| = -1$. So the function is negative semi-definite and quasi-concave?

Comment: There is an answer in this post:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422875/how-to-determine-whether-a-function-is-concave-convex-quasi-concave-and-quasi